# mysql 5.6: remove explicit column collate

Tags: mysql, collation, ddl, mysql-5.6, collate

I am running mysql 5.6.

Some of the columns in a schema that I inherited from previous developers have an explicitly specified `collate` clause.

All explicitly specified `collate` clauses are the same as the database's default `collate`.

Is there any way to remove the explicit column `collate` clauses?

There should be no functional collating differences versus my current `collate`, but I want the following:

1. to get column definitions sans `collate` clauses when I request a
   `create table` statement from mysql (I want to be able to compare
   table creation scripts from a code repository with `create table`
   statements obtained from different instances of the schema on
   different mysql servers; the explicit column `collate` clauses are
   only in some instances, but not others, which would require me to
   use a more complex diff than a plain text diff)
2. to have the `collate` of these columns automatically change to
   whatever is the new default database `collate` if I ever change it

1) is much more important than 2), however, since I will probably never change the `collate` again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, fetch the equivalent data from `information_schema` tables `TABLES` and `COLUMNS`.

Meanwhile, do you have an example of the `COLLATION` clause being present in some cases, but not in other cases?

Comment: I no longer work for the company with these tables, so I don’t have examples. We had schema creation scripts, so the point was to compare the current VCS versions with whatever the running database had. Selecting info from the `information_schema` tables would have required us to reconstruct `create table` statements ourselves from the data, which would take extra effort, and possible be error-prone. Plus, that only deals with issue 1, not issue 2.